# Strange query from Thinking Sphinx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I've been having a problem with Thinking Sphinx's query generation. I would input a query like '"jack | "the bean stalk" | jill | jeffrey", and instead of the expected fast index loop, I get the slow SQL query:

> SELECT  table.id, table.FullName FROM `table`  WHERE
>   (LOWER(table.FullName) LIKE '%jack or \"the bean stalk\" or jill or
>   jeffrey%')  ORDER BY table.FullName ASC LIMIT 10

This query is strange for a number of reasons. First, instead of a boolean lookup, I get a wildcard lookup of a misceginated version of the query. Second, it is searching ordered by FullName, when I requested some other field to order by (LastName).

I know that Thinking Sphinx will bypass its index and drop into native SQL queries when sorting against a column that was not specified :sortable => true, and it will do so on columns that are not strings. However neither is the case here.

Why is it dropping into native SQL?

Answer (score 0):

I am absolutely certain that Thinking Sphinx is not making that SQL query. I wonder: do you have other gems (in your Gemfile, or perhaps as dependencies of other gems?) that add search functionality that may be getting in the way? For example, I know `activeadmin` has a dependency on `meta_search`.

One possible way around this is to have `activeadmin` (or whatever the gem that's causing this problem is) listed *before* `thinking-sphinx` in your Gemfile (and thus, TS gets loaded after, and inserts the `search` method that you're expecting).